# LINQ query to include the parent name in the child item

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public bool MarkAsPresent { get; set; }

    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

Please someone can help? From ASP.NET Core API controller, I need to return the following JSON. Please note that in the OrderItems, it includes the Product.ProductName. Also, if the Order.MarkAsPresent is true, then the productName should be replaced as 'Gift' in the JSON data.

```
{
    "order": {
        "orderId": "123",
        "orderDate": "01-May-2021",
        "orderItems": [
            { "productName": "Pen", "quantity": "25", "retailPrice": "3.50" },
            { "productName": "Paper", "quantity": "500", "retailPrice": "5.50" },
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the default settings in dotnet core will just do that already

Comment: What does this have to do with LINQ? Are you selecting this data out of a database with a LINQ query, or do you already have the C# objects in memory and just need to turn them into JSON?

Comment: @brianberns Yes, these objects are going to be retrieved from the database.

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight Can you please explain?

Comment: *these objects are going to be retrieved from the database* And how? If by Entity Framework, please choose an appropriate tag and mention the exact version.

Comment: @beastieboy Sorry, I didn't read the question fully. Potential anwer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it  using an OrderDto.

```
        public class OrderDto
        {
           public int OrderId { get; set; }
           public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

           public object OrderItems { get; set; }

           public OrderDto(int orderId, DateTime orderDate)
           {
              OrderId = orderId;
              OrderDate = orderDate;
           }
        }//Cls

        //--------------------------------------------//

        public class OrderItemDto
        {
           public string ProductName { get; set; }
           public int Quantity { get; set; }
           public decimal RetailPrice { get; set; }
           public OrderItemDto(string giftName, int quantity, decimal retailPrice)
           {
              ProductName = giftName;
              Quantity = quantity;
              RetailPrice = retailPrice;
           }
        }//Cls

        //--------------------------------------------//

        public class GiftDto
        {
           public string GiftName { get; set; }
           public int Quantity { get; set; }
           public decimal RetailPrice { get; set; }

           public GiftDto(string giftName, int quantity, decimal retailPrice)
           {
              GiftName = giftName;
              Quantity = quantity;
              RetailPrice = retailPrice;
           }
        }//Cls
```

Add this method to your Order class

```
   public class Order
        {
           public int OrderId { get; set; }
           public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
           public bool MarkAsPresent { get; set; }

           public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }

           public OrderDto ToDto()
           {
              var dto = new OrderDto(OrderId, OrderDate);
              if (MarkAsPresent)
                 dto.OrderItems = OrderItems.Select(oi => new GiftDto(oi.Product.ProductName, oi.Quantity, oi.Price));
              else
                 dto.OrderItems = OrderItems.Select(oi => new OrderItemDto(oi.Product.ProductName, oi.Quantity, oi.Price));

              return dto;
           }
        }//Cls
```

Then in your action return something like `Ok(order.ToDto());`
Examples:

```
       [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult OrderGift()
        {
           var order = new Order()
           {
              OrderId = 1,
              OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
              MarkAsPresent = true
           };
           order.OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();

           for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
           {
              order.OrderItems.Add(
                 new OrderItem()
                 {
                    Order = order,
                    OrderId = order.OrderId,
                    OrderItemId = i + 10,
                    Price = (i + 1) * 10,
                    Product = new Product()
                    {
                       ProductId = i + 20,
                       ProductName = $"Name {i}"
                    },
                    ProductId = i + 20,
                    Quantity = i * 2 + 4

                 });
           }//for

           return Ok(order.ToDto());

        }///OrderGift


        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult OrderRegular()
        {
           var order = new Order()
           {
              OrderId = 1,
              OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
              MarkAsPresent = false
           };
           order.OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();

           for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
           {
              order.OrderItems.Add(
                 new OrderItem()
                 {
                    Order = order,
                    OrderId = order.OrderId,
                    OrderItemId = i + 10,
                    Price = (i + 1) * 10,
                    Product = new Product()
                    {
                       ProductId = i + 20,
                       ProductName = $"Name {i}"
                    },
                    ProductId = i + 20,
                    Quantity = i * 2 + 4

                 });
           }//for

           return Ok(order.ToDto());

        }//OrderRegular
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking your time for providing the answer

Answer (score 2):

The two answers given so far are far too cumbersome. There's a very common, standard way to do this:

```cs
var result = from o in context.Order
    select new
    {
        o.OrderId,
        o.OrderDate,
        OrderItems =
            from oi in o.OrderItems
            select new
            {
                ProductName = o.MarkAsPresent
                    ? "Gift"
                    : oi.Product.ProductName,
                oi.Quantity,
                RetailPrice = oi.Price
            }
    };
```

You didn't define `RetailPrice`, so I assume it's just `OrderItem.Price`. If you like, the two `select new` statement can be replaced by projections into named DTO classes like `OrderDto` and `OrderItemDto`, respectively.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Both your answer and ShanieMoonlight worked. In view of the extra efforts that ShanieMoonlight took for making the answer complete, I had to accept his response as the answer. I really appreciate your answer as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: Verbosity vs simplicity, but OK, your call.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Linq's [let clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause):

```
var report = 
    from o in orders
    let orderItems = 
        from oi in o.OrderItems
        select new { 
            productName = o.MarkAsPresent ? "Gift" : oi.Product.ProductName, 
            quantity = oi.Quantity, 
            retailPrice = oi.Price 
        }
    select new {
        orderId = o.OrderId,
        orderDate = o.OrderDate,
        orderItems
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **join** to join the two models so we can connect every properties, and **group** all the
data by

OrderId and OrderDate, then just select the property you want to show.

About the gift,you can use if else in select.

Following is my demo:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        var model = (from e in _context.OrderItems.Include(x=>x.Order).ToList()
                     join y in _context.Products.ToList() on e.OrderItemId equals y.ProductId
                     group new { e, y } by new {  e.OrderId, e.Order.OrderDate } into g
                     select new
                     {
                         order = new
                         {
                             orderId = g.Key.OrderId,
                             orderDate = g.Key.OrderDate,
                             orderItems = (
                              from t in g.ToList()
                              select new
                              {
                                  productName = t.e.Order.MarkAsPresent == true ? "Gift" : t.y.ProductName,
                                  quantity = t.e.Quantity,
                                  retailPrice = t.e.Price
                              }
                             ).ToList()
                         }
                     }).ToList();

        return new JsonResult(model);
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: No, don't use `join`. Always use navigation properties. Also, using `ToList()` twice is very inefficient. You should stay in `IQueryable` as long a possible.

Comment: @Tisa, Many thanks for your response. I guess the second line is meant to be:
 join y in _context.Products.ToList() on e.ProductId equals y.ProductId

For some reason I get the following error:
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'

Also, it would be helpful if you could specify the equivalent LINQ method syntax as well.  Many thanks for your time!